# In the user page, the grey square "About me" It says I can use < a > tags, How do I do that?

Tags: support, user-interface, profile-page, stack-exchange

In the user page, the Grey square "About me" It says I can use `< a >` tags, How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Click the **edit** link next to the About Me box and just add in the links as you would a normal HTML page.

There are some restrictions to keep in mind though, and it's a [slightly greater restriction than on a regular question post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-sofu).

```
<a href="http://meta.doctype.com/">Feeling the pain of UserVoice</a> all 
over again.
```

The links are `nofollow`, and if you get excessive, it won't play.

Comment: Tried that, not working

Comment: @Itay: [Works on my machine!](http://haacked.com/images/haacked_com/WindowsLiveWriter/UsefulMVC2UpgradeTip_EC18/works-on-my-machine_3.png)